# Combine multiple rows of the same column into one row

Tags: crystal-reports

I have following data from my database:

```
+------+-----------+-------------+---------------+
|  ID  | SomeValue |  SomeDate   | SomeOtherDate |
+------+-----------+-------------+---------------+
| 123  |     12345 |  01.01.2017 |    01.01.2018 |
| 123  |     54321 |  01.01.2017 |    01.01.2019 |
| 123  |     25314 |  01.01.2017 |    01.01.2020 |
+------+-----------+-------------+---------------+
```

I want the following format in Crystal Reports:

```
+------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|  ID  | SomeValue2018 | SomeValue2019 | SomeValue2020 |
+------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| 123  |         12345 |         54321 |         25314 |
+------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

How can I do this, if it's even possible? I've tried multiple examples but cant seem to make it work. I was successfully able to make the headings.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to make Crystal Reports evaluate things horizontally. The entire system is designed to evaluate vertically. (Things on the top of a report are evaluated before things below them.)

However you might be able to get a **CrossTab** to do this. First you'd want to make a new Forumla field for your columns. It would be structured something like:

```
"SomeValue" + Year({@SomeOtherDate})
```

When you design the crosstab, you'll want to set `ID` as the Row, your new formula from above as the Column, and the Summarized Field will be `SomeValue`. You'll also want to suppress the Grand Totals in the Customize Style.